# Migrating mySql2 to postgreSQL : query cache type error when mysql2psql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, migration

So I'm migrating my development environment and production environment to postgresql so that I can deploy to Heroku. After installing the mysql2psql gem, initializing a (postgresql)database.yml file- I'm stuck at the point where I run mysql2psql. After running it I get the following:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2psql-0.1.0/bin/../lib/mysql2psql/mysql_reader.rb:153:in `query': Query cache is disabled; restart the server with query_cache_type=1 to enable it
```

so the questions is how can I restart my mysql2 server and specify the query_cache_type=1?

I've tried to start the server with the following and it hasen't worked:

```
mysql --query_cache_type=1;
```

After trying several similar commands, I tried starting the server and then doing it in the session:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL query_cache_type = 1;
```

but alas I get:

```
ERROR 1651 (HY000): Query cache is disabled; restart the server with query_cache_type=1 to enable it
```

**This is really a syntax question:** what command do I use to start my sql server with the option query_cache_type=1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Mac OS X 10.8 the my.cnf file could be in the folder /usr/local/mysql-5.6.10-osx10.7-x86_64

Search in Terminal with

```
$ find / -name my.cnf
```

to find it on your system.

Edit your my.cnf file by adding this line at the end

```
query_cache_type=1
```

Restart your mysqld in the System Preferences, if you've installed the MySQL Preference Pane (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/macosx-installation-prefpane.html), or in Terminal by writing

```
$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart
```

and then log in to mysql with

```
$ mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

and write

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL query_cache_size=40000;
```

If you then run

```
$ mysql2psql
```

in the Rails app folder it should convert your database.

Comment: If I could give you 10 upvotes, I would give you 10 upvotes. Big +1

Comment: Restart your mysqld in the System Preferences -> How?

Comment: @Magne Updated the answer to explain how to restart your mysqld

Answer (score 1):

Just set it in your my.cnf file, usually located in /etc? Then restart.

EDIT:

Also you need to have a query_cache_size set, if one of those two settings are set to zero then it won't be enabled.

Comment: I tried to do this by creating my own my.cnf file(there wasn't one there by default). I added the following line SET query_cache_type=1; and restarted the server-(via the system preferences) but it didn't work. Suggestions? I feel like there's a really simple configuration that I'm missing.